# Mod rewrite: redirect on trailing slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a .htaccess file in which I'm attempting to redirect requests to

```
/something/
```

to

```
/something
```

...after which a second rule should run which turns

```
/something
```

...into

```
/index.php?foo=something
```

Here's my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

#rule 1 - disallow trailing slash
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)\/$ $1

#rule 2 - main redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(inc/) [NC]
RewriteRule ^[a-z\-]+$ index.php?foo=$0
```

Both rules take effect correctly, but the redirect in the first rule goes to a 404 and I can't see why. The correct flow should be:

- Request URL: http://localhost/mysite/something/ Gets redirected to:
- http://localhost/mysite/something (via 1st rule) Gets redirected to:
- http://localhost/mysite/index.php?foo=something (via 2nd rule)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `R` flag to redirect:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine on

#rule 1 - disallow trailing slash
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)\/$ $1 [L,R]

#rule 2 - main redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(inc/) [NC]
RewriteRule ^[a-z\-]+$ index.php?foo=$0
```

Also, you *may* need to turn `DirectorySlash` off, because mod_dir will automatically append trailing slashes to diretories. If you dont turn that off, it might cause a redirect loop.

Additionally, you *may* also need a `RewriteBase` directive if these rules are in an htaccess file that isn't in your document root.

```
RewriteBase /
```

for document root, but in your question you have URLs that look like `http://localhost/mysite/something/` and if the rules are in `/mysite/` you need:

```
RewriteBase /mysite/
```

Comment: OK now that does something REALLY weird: if I go to a page with a trailing slash, it (visibly) redirects me to my local machine with a messed up URL like `http://localhost/c:/xampp...`

Comment: @Utkanos did you setup a rewrite base?

Comment: @Utkanos the second part of my answer, the *`RewriteBase`* directive.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give this a go and report back.